# Flask-SocketIO: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I created a simple chat website, https://ezchat.xyz and sometimes it randomly gives me this error and doesn't send the message, but it doensn't crash

[website code](https://github.com/ssebastianoo/ezchat)

[image: error]

[image: apache configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
I found out that only the first message sent was broken, so I just sent a "fake" message on the connect socket event